# Resize embedded user controls in a panel C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

Using WinForms in C#, I'm struggling to get an embedded user control to resize correctly. I can add it to the panel with no issue, and the panel resizes as I expect (and want) it to.

To add the UserControl, I'm doing the following:

```
content.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
content.Controls.Add(c);
content.Controls[0].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
content.Refresh();
```

I cannot figure out how to get the newly added control to resize properly, I've also tried using Anchor with Top,Bottom,Left,Right but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding below will resize the user control with the parent control size.

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

But, if you want to resize the child controls of your user control you will have to set their dock values and anchor values properly. Otherwise, the main user control will resize but the inner child controls of the user control will stay as they are.

You have said;

*<< the control moves down, instead of resizing down*

If there are some child controls that you want to stretch vertically you might try [FlowLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171633.aspx) panel.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that there was a phantom panel somewhere in the mix, but going over everything and adding `this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` seems to have done what I wanted. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% sure that Controls[0] is in fact referrencing your control after the add?

Your local var to the control is still valid, you could test that you are setting dock to the right thing by `c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: Using content.Controls[c.Name].Dock = DockStyle.Fill; has the same outcome (that is, it doesn't resize at all).

Comment: Adding this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill in the UserControl seems to help slightly, but still doesn't resize correctly (the control moves down, instead of resizing down)

Comment: @Joeb: Then you need to properly define the Dock/Anchor of the controls inside of your user control.  The framework can't magically know how you want these things to resize.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.
At the panel which is the base for all added panels add the handler for the `Resize` event.
At the `OnResize()` add:

```
    private void SummaryData_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MyPanel pan in this.Controls)
        {
            pan.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
```

It worked for me.
I've debugged the code and it seems at the `OnResize` all my `panels` lost their Dock setting.